# Texas Hold'em Probability Question

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, poker

In a game of Texas Hold'Em you are dealt: 4 of hearts and 5 of hearts

The flop: 2-club, 6-spade, K-Diamond.

Define set S1 as 7-card hands that contain the 5 revealed cards AND contain a straight AND its turn and river are 7 and 8, regardless of order.

What is the size of S1?

Define set S2 as 7-card hands that contain the 5 revealed cards AND contain a straight AND its turn and river contain 3.

What is the size of S2?

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the first, the 5 cards are absolute, for the turn and river, there are four 7's and four 8's, so I guess S1's size is ${4 \choose 1} * {4 \choose 1} = 16$

For the second: it has to contain straight, it must contain 3 and it already has 2, 4, 5 and 6, which means that way it already has a straight. There are four 3's in the deck, so there are ${4 \choose 1}$ ways to pick up a 3. As for the 7'th card, it can be any card. How many cards are left after all this selection? $52-6 = 46$. So totally it's ${4 \choose 1} * 46 = 184$

Comment: @Raj is it alright?

Comment: Yes the first one is right, but the second one is wrong. I am not sure which part is wrong in that

Comment: It says "turn and river contain 3." so I am guessing that means both the 6th and 7th cards are 3s?

Comment: @Raj Are you sure both of them needs to be 3? so it's not what I wrote, it's ${4 \choose 2}$ because you need two 3's from four availabe 3's

Comment: Notice the S2 has TWO parts..  How do you calculate the part where it says " contain the 5 revealed cards AND contain a straight" What are the possibilities for that? I am assuming its the answer to that multiple by 4 choose 2?

Comment: I looked at it as one part - if the 7-cards set contains the 5 revealed cards AND contains a straight AND turn or river contains 3, so it already has a straight. May I know the right answer so I can point out my mistake?

Comment: I don't know the right answer. If I figure it out. I will post it here

Comment: It does not contain a straight in the 5 cards given. To get a straight, the remaining two cards (turn and river) must either be {7,8} or contain 3.

Comment: But it says it contains 3, so you have a straight! I've done some calculations and I think my answer is true. If you get another one, I'll be happy to know :)